# EJB invocations from a remote client using JNDI?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, wildfly-10, sasl

I wrote a war application deployed on wildfly 9.0.2 final based on "EJB invocations from a remote client using JNDI" example on jboss documentation.

The app connects to a remote EJB inside war deployment on wildfly 10.

I am getting this exception and am seeking help resolving it:

> ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting
>   "client-endpoint" I/O-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed:
>   javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all
>   available authentication mechanisms failed:
>
> DIGEST-MD5: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: DIGEST-MD5: Cannot
>   perform callback to acquire realm, authentication ID or password
>   [Caused by javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException]
>
> 14:00:27,058 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) Could not register a EJB receiver
>   for connection to remote ip server:7273: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all
>   available authentication mechanisms failed:
>
> DIGEST-MD5: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: DIGEST-MD5: Cannot
>   perform callback to acquire realm, authentication ID or password
>   [Caused by javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException]

I used `adduser` script for create user pass in `applicationrealm` mode and I watched `standalone-full.xml` in subsystem remoting section that `applicationrealm` used for realm. I cannot detect any problem with this.

Should add any more `config` to `standalone-full.xml` to improve my app?

Comment: perhaps it would be helpful to see the corresponding examples for wildfly 9 on github's wildfly quickstart (they have branches for wildfly 8, 9 and 10).